# ¿Por qué solo funciona al poner el punto de interrupción en el procedimiento?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   private void enOtroHiloHuella()
    {
        IniciarCaptura();
    }

    protected void IniciarCaptura()
    {

        if (Captura != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Captura.StartCapture();
            }
            catch (Exception t)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NO SE PUDO INICIAR LA CAPTURA" + t.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Es medio raro pero cierto si no esta el punto de interrupción no llega a crearse el hilo de lo contrario si lo hace ahi en el código muestra que hace en el hilo pero se ejecuta cuando esta el punto de interrupción y avanzo con F11 por paso  alguien sabe porque sucede eso

Comment: hola. podrias ser mucho mas claro? usa el boton [edit] para agregar informacion sobre que quieres hacer, que es lo que realmente hace, y cual es el objetivo. asi como esta, la pregunta no se puede responder. mira [ask] y haz el [tour] si no lo hiciste.

Comment: ya lo edite ...

Comment: no llega a crearse... o se crea y se muere?? algo me huele mal.. el thread esta definido internamente en la clase.. lo inicia, pero pierde la referencia enseguida al terminar el evento click... puede ser???

Comment: No llega a crearse porque nose inicia la captura de huella pero si yo le pongo el punto de interrupcion y lo hago correr por paso si se crea e inicia la captura de huella

Comment: probaste definir la variable s a nivel del form? lee mi comentario, pierdes la referencia al otro thread...

Comment: Yo como siempre recomiendo no usar **nunca** la clase `Thread`. Es muy compleja de manejar incluso para expertos. Tenemos a nuestra disposicion `BackgroundWorker` y `Task` que son mas sencillas y potentes.

Comment: A priori lo mejor seria usar un background y dentro de ese metodo llamar al DoWork

Comment: Cuando usas thread no esta bueno definir variables de forma global (mas que nada por problemas de concurrencia), como es el caso de "Captura" que estas evaluando, puede que al depurar funcione porque estas evitando este problema de evaluacion. Trata de definir las variables de foma local en el thread

Comment: les cuento que ya probe con el BackgroundWorker y pasa lo mismo funciona cuando le pongo  el punto de interrupcion  pero cuando lo quito y lo hago correr no funciona . Lo que quiero hacer esq al minimizar el formulario siga capturando las huellas y me notifique quien ingresa porque al minimizar el formulario ya no captura por eso intento con una tarea en segundo plano

Comment: entiendo que esto involucra el acceso a un dispositivo, estas seguro que este soporta el uso de thread ?  cuando dices que no funciona como evaluas, no obtienes ningun exception, no uses el messagebox, no es bueno dentro de un thread, quiza el try..catch y valida si falla

Comment: Pero yo digo porque funciona cuando lo hago compilar paso a paso y no funciona cuando compila de forma normal